# Kali Linux installation messed up my Windows

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, grub, uefi

I installed Kali last night hoping to dual-boot it with my Windows. Grub is having issues recognizing Windows however and I can no longer get into the system. I tried running `boot-repair`, but to no avail. Here's my [pastebin file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7frHCcZnjM/). I've also tried running `update-grub` from Kali but the system can't see the Windows boot image. The partition is still fine but I just can't get into it. How should I proceed?

Comment: Try some of [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows).

Comment: Please paste the relevant details within the question, not as an external link. External links go dead, make the question hard to search for, and are generally disliked by many people (frequently rife with ads, requires another tab, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows was/is booting in native UEFI mode, but your GRUB bootloader for Kali has been installed to use the legacy BIOS mode, probably because you booted the Kali installer using the legacy mode.

The problem is that any BIOS-style bootloader cannot start any UEFI-style bootloader at all. A BIOS-style bootloader uses 16-bit code and is supported by 16-bit firmware code. A native UEFI bootloader, in your case, uses 64-bit code and is supported by 64-bit firmware code. While the bootloader certainly could switch the processor to full 64-bit mode, it has no way to access the 64-bit firmware resources, since the firmware's BIOS compatibility support module has specifically hidden them away to make the system as 16-bit compatible as possible. At the same time, the BIOS compatibility support module has hidden away the interface a running OS can use to edit UEFI boot settings, known as "UEFI run-time services".

A complete fix to this problem would require access to UEFI run-time services, so fixing this from within a legacy-booted Kali would be difficult. The suggested repair - replacing the `grub-pc` package (= the legacy BIOS version of the GRUB bootloader) with the corresponding `grub-efi-amd64[-signed]` would be the right thing to do, but it alone would not be a complete fix. (The -signed suffix is needed if your system has Secure Boot enabled.)

The next step would be registering the new UEFI GRUB bootloader into firmware NVRAM, so it will appear in your BIOS settings. Whether `boot-repair` can do that or not depends on which boot mode was used when `boot-repair` was started: was it started in native UEFI mode, or using the legacy BIOS compatibility?

Also, it looks like the `boot-repair` might not be detecting Kali properly, as I think it was designed for Ubuntu(?).

If you want to go back to Windows, you should check your BIOS boot order settings, to make sure Windows is set as the first OS to boot. If your BIOS settings include any options to select whether native UEFI or legacy BIOS boot methods are preferred, you should switch it to prefer native UEFI over legacy methods.